# How to get rows from Google Sheets filtered by a column's value?

Tags: curl, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this : (this is just a snippet of my sheet, it might have 10,000 rows in the future)

[image: spreadsheet image]

What I want to do is, Get every row whose `For Class (column)` value = `7` - In above sample case, rows `#3, #5, #8, #10` have the `For Class` value of `7`, so I should get them.

Using this reference - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get, I tried to get some data : (range is just `Sheet3` because I want all the rows available)

[image: trial image]

But as you can see, since I haven't applied any filters, it just gives me everything - (I require that the majorDimension should be `ROWS`)

[image: trial results]

What should I do, in order to get all rows containing `For Class = 7`, keeping the majorDimension to `ROWS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

There's no way to filter rows based on a column value **during the Sheets API request**. There's [batchGetByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGetByDataFilter), but it only allows you to filter according to a specified range or according to [DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata#DeveloperMetadata).

#### Workaround:

That said, you can easily filter that data after receiving the response from the API. I don't know what language you are using, but for example, if you were using Node, it could be something like:

```
const filteredRows = response["values"].filter(row => row[0] == "7");
console.log(filteredRows);
```

Where `response` corresponds to the API response from [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).